# Java socket accepts only headers

Tags: java, sockets, curl

I listen port on localhost.I'm using next code fore it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    listenPort(9000);
}

private static void listenPort(Integer portNumber) {
    try (
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    ) {
        System.out.println("Port " + portNumber + " is listening");
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After code running I execute post request using curl:

```
curl localhost:9000 -d foo
```

This is my console output:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 3
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Curl process is waiting for something and request body "foo" appears in console only after curl interrupt. Same occurs when socket accepts request from remote clients.

Comment: Crul' default protocol is http - take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CURL is assuming that your server is a well-behaving HTTP server, so it's simply waiting for a response, but your server never sends one, which causes CURL to wait indefinitely for it.

The word "foo" doesn't show up because CURL sends the following data (I added whitespace and the data part):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: localhost:9000\r\n
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Content-Length: 3\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
\r\n
foo
```

The readLine function will simply read the stream until it sees "\n" and then it will return that. But the last line of the data that CURL sends actually doesn't contain any "\n" characters and, since the socket and the stream are not closed, readLine() will simply block, waiting for the "\n" character that will never come.

If you close the connection by quitting CURL, the socket will be closed as well, which closes the stream, which causes readLine() to return.

In order to fix these problems you probably shouldn't use readLine(). Also you should read about how [HTTP works on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) if you want to learn how to implement a well-behaved HTTP server.

Otherwise I'd recommend using an already existing Java based HTTP server like [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) or just plain old [Java Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet).

Comment: I suppose that you mean `\r\n` (the MS Windows line separator) ? (not the other way around)

Comment: Yes, of course. I edited the answer. Though in this case it is actually the HTTP mandated line separator, which is OS independent.